# Problema al añadir CKeditor

Tags: javascript, html

No me sale [`ckeditor`](http://ckeditor.com/) añadido.

Y éste es mi código:

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace('prueba');
</script>
<textarea name="prueba" id="prueba" class="form-control"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona?

Comment: Lo único que  he cambiado ha sido tu `<`script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` para poder reproducir el problema en el editor de código de stackoverflow.

Comment: me aparece un textarea normal no el de ckeditor.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionarme la URL en la que te ocurre? Si es un desarrollo local, ¿podrías comprobar la consola de depuración para ver si te fallaba la carga del javascript?

Comment: me pone a no esta definido, y es en la linea de un archivo de ckeditor

Comment: Pero antes de eso ¿no te da un mensaje diciendo que no pudo descargarse? Es decir, algo así: `GET https://stacksnippets.net/bac/ckeditor.js` con un aspa roja al lado. ¿Qué navegador usas?

Comment: que va, uso firefox pero chrome tampoco me va

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código completo de tu página? Recuerda pegar el contenido editando tu pregunta, luego volver a seleccionar todo y pulsar en el botón `{}` para que se convierta en código. **[Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58640/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-bsg).**

Comment: ¿podrías entrar al chat o responder a lo que te dije? ¿Dónde descargaste el script? Si en vez de usar `/ckeditor/ckeditor.js` pones `ckeditor/ckeditor.js` o `ckeditor.js` se soluciona?

Comment: me salía el mismo error cambiando la ruta, el archivo es descargado directamente desde su web

Comment: ¿El archivo lo descargaste en el mismo sitio donde tienes la página? ¿se creó el subdirectorio llamado `ckeditor`? A veces, si usamos el botón derecho para descomprimir, es posible que se termine descomprimiendo en `ckeditor_4.6_TIPO/ckeditor`. Además, te recomiendo usar rutas relativas (`ckeditor/ckeditor.js` en vez de `/ckeditor/ckeditor.js`). ¿Podrías comprobar la ruta donde se descomprimió ckeditor?

Comment: si se creo la carpeta ckeditor y las rutas relativas las he probado.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, me ayudaron a descubrir qué te ocurría para poder redactar una respuesta explicándote el problema que sufrías y diferentes maneras de solucionarlo. Espero que te sea útil :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según parece has descargado correctamente `ckeditor` pero has intentado llamar a una función antes de haber sido definida en su archivo de script.

A continuación te enumero diferentes errores que se pueden producir por hacer la llamada a una función javascript en un momento erróneo y al final te explico qué ventajas tiene la ejecución asíncrona del trabajo.

**(MAL) Ejecución antes de cargar `ckeditor`**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 CKEDITOR.replace('prueba');
</script>
<textarea name="prueba" id="prueba" class="form-control"></textarea>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Provoca un error `Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined` porque has intentado llamar a una función que se define en un script cargado posteriormente.

**(MAL) Ejecutar antes de generar el DOM**

```html
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 CKEDITOR.replace('prueba');
</script>
<textarea name="prueba" id="prueba" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

En este caso se genera un error del tipo `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined` debido a que hemos intentado acceder a un elemento del DOM antes de generarlo.

**Orden correcto**

```html
<textarea name="prueba" id="prueba" class="form-control"></textarea>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 CKEDITOR.replace('prueba');
</script>
```

Todos los scripts deben cargarse al final del documento HTML para que se interprete su contenido sin esperar a la carga de éstos.

**Uso de `async` y `defer` para acelerar la carga de la página**

En [esta página web](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html) puedes ver cómo se pueden usar `async` y `defer` para hacer ésto definiendo los scripts en la parte superior, para obtener la misma funcionalidad, pero en ese caso no puedes ejecutar el script al final del documento, si no que [debes esperar al evento `onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) o bien de `window` o bien del propio script:

```html
<textarea name="prueba" id="prueba" class="form-control"></textarea>
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js" defer onload="trabaja()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function trabaja() {
   CKEDITOR.replace('prueba');
  }
</script>
```

Si se usa `defer` en vez de `async` no importaría el orden en el que pongas las cosas en el documento ya que el javascript no se ejecuta hasta finalizar la carga tanto del propio script como del HTML y, por lo tanto, se garantiza que `prueba` está en el DOM cuando se llame a `trabaja()` en el evento `onload` y que esta función ha sido también definida.

Si usáramos `async` entonces simplemente deberíamos asegurarnos que se define `prueba` y la función `trabaja()` antes de cargar el javascript de `ckeditor.js` para asegurarnos que la función está definida en el momento de la carga y que ya existe el elemento en el DOM.

---

La principal ventaja de la carga asíncrona es que la página no se detiene durante el tiempo que dura la descarga del javascript y su ejecución, haciendo que aparentemente la página cargue en menos tiempo:

[image: Gráfico ilustrativo]

Aunque recomiendo, aún así, poner todo en el orden correcto para que no falle la carga en navegadores muy antiguos y, además, ganemos en velocidad de carga en los nuevos.

Answer (score 2):

Con tu código puesto así funciona:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea name="prueba" id="prueba" class="form-control"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('prueba');
</script>
```

Comment: tengo solo eso y un menú y un pie.

Comment: prueba a cargar el script desde el cdn por si es un problema de tu copia local

Comment: A eso es a lo que voy con mis comentarios. Recuerda que debes comentar en su pregunta, no como respuesta (si empiezan a entrar a esta pregunta y ven tu respuesta puede ser que te lleves algún negativo).

Comment: vale me funciono lo de cdn muchas gracias

Comment: La razón era poner el código probado, no tengo ningún problema en borrar la respuesta. De nada, ibamos por el mismo camino desde los comentarios Oscar y yo

Comment: El objetivo es encontrar su error. Si ha descargado el script y lo quiere usar en local, habrá que indicarle por qué no lo carga. Si no lo ha descargado hay que indicarle que use el CDN. La respuesta se escribe cuando uno tiene certeza de cuál es la solución al problema que se plantea.